# Select all similar rows that are possible duplicates using LIKE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

After importing information about songs into my SQLite database, I want to use a SELECT statement to find all possible duplicate songs using this criteria:

songName in one row similar or equal to the songName in any other row in the same table (Songs) AND artistID is the same in both rows.  This should work without knowing the contents of songName.  If I wanted to compare a known song name to all others in the database that can be done using "songName LIKE '%known name%'", but how do I find all duplicates without this?

**Example Songs Table:**

```
id  songName            artistID  duration
--------------------------------------------
0  This is a song       5         3:43
1  Another song         3         3:23
2  01-This is a song    5         3:42
3  song                 4         4:01
4  song                 4         6:33
5  Another record       2         2:45
```

**Expected Results:**

```
id  songName            artistID  duration
--------------------------------------------
0   This is a song      5         3:43
2   01-This is a song   5         3:42
3   song                4         4:01
4   song                4         6:33
```

**EDIT:**

Since the idea of creating a hash and comparing them has been suggested, I'm thinking about using this psuedo-function to create a hash for each song name:

```
Public Function createHash(ByVal phrase As String) As String
    'convert to lower case
    phrase = LCase(phrase)

    'split the phrase into words
    Dim words() As String = phrase.Replace("_", " ").Split(" ")

    Dim hash As String = ""
    For w = 0 To words.Count - 1
        'remove noise words (a, an, the, etc.)
        words(w) = removeNoiseWords(words(w))
        'convert 1 or 2-digit numbers to corresponding words
        words(w) = number2word(words(w))
    Next

    'rebuild using replaced words and remove spaces
    hash = String.Join("", words)

    'convert upper ascii into alphabetic (ie. ñ = n, Ö = O, etc.)
    hash = removeUnsupChars(hash, True)

    'strip away all remaining non-alphanumeric characters
    hash = REGEX_Replace(hash, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
    Return hash
End Function
```

Once the hash is computed, I'll store that with each record and then select duplicates using a count(hash)>1.  I'll then use .NET code to see if the artistID is the same for the returned records.

This solution seems to be working fine so far.  Here is the SQLite statement I use to find the duplicate songs:

```
SELECT count(*),hash from Songs GROUP BY hash HAVING count(hash) > 1 ORDER BY hash;
```

This gives me a list of all the hashes that occur more than once.  I store these results in an array, then cycle through the array and simply use this statement to get the detailed info:

```
    For i = 0 To dupeHashes.Count - 1
        SQLconnect.Open()
        SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
        SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from Songs WHERE hash = '" & dupeHashes(i) & "';"
        SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()
        While SQLreader.Read()
            'get whatever data needed for each duplicate song
        End While
        SQLcommand.Dispose()
        SQLconnect.Close()
    Next
```

Comment: [SQLite Full Text Search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) is what you'd use to retrieve rows that match.

Comment: It's all in the [markdown documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - the link used to be accessible when adding/editing questions :(

Comment: I see.  Back to your suggestion.  I took a quick look at full text searches, but can you provide an example?  I don't see how to compare two unknowns (songName "x" to all other songNames).

Comment: The "Simple FTS Queries" provides examples how to search using FTS

Comment: The only way I can see that this would work would be if I selected all the songnames from the entire table, then in a for loop used something like "SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE songName MATCH " & allSongs(i) in VB.Net, but this would take forever scanning 50,000 records... right?

Comment: Is it just me, or have we seen a lot of song related sql questions lately. All of which have similar sql table structures, but not the same question asker...odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would add an extra field where you compute some sort of "hash" of the title. A good function for this would be stripping away every non-alphabetic character, including spaces, drop any article (like "the", "a", "an") then compute the [soundex code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) for the title and prefixing this with the artistId string.

So in your case you would get:

```
id  songName            artistID  duration  Hash
----------------------------------------------------
0  This is a song       5         3:43      5.T0021
1  Another song         3         3:23      3.A9872
2  01-This is a song    5         3:42      5.T0021
3  song                 4         4:01      4.S0332
4  song                 4         6:33      4.S0332
5  Another record       2         2:45      2.A7622
```

From now on, getting only the rows having ...count(Hash)>1 should be easy...

Note also that I suggest Soundex but you can make your own function, or adapt an existing one, making some elements more relevant than others.

Comment: I thought about using soundex, but the results were a lot of false positives.  I do like the idea of pre-computing a hash of some type and storing it with each record.  So far, I think this is the most promising solution.

Comment: The wikipedia page mentions some alternatives which made the encoding more accurate. Also, did you drop the articles in front of the title (a, an, the, this...)? Soundex really cares mostly about the first part of the string. And maybe you could just try something like keeping only the first 7 consonants and dropping everything else - remember that you are prefixing this with the singer id...

Comment: I really don't care about "sounds-like" matches.  I want a more exact match than that, plus there are many song names that begin the same way that will return as possible duplicates.  Look at the edit to my original question to see what I have in mind.

Comment: @comp, if it sounds like it then it is most likely an exact match. If you had 2 songs named "Tammie My Love" and "Tammy My Love", wouldn't you want them to match? Sounds like matching soves this.  I've used this method in the past to suggest names that already exist based on what the user typed and it worked flawlessly. I was even able to calculate the likelihood that it was a match and display it as part of the query results.

Comment: However, `SOUNDEX` only cares about the first 2 syllables. If you want fewer false positives, create a `SOUNDEX` hash from each real word in the song name and store it in a table with the song id attached. Then run an query on that table find the most likely matches.

Comment: @kevin: I would love for soundex to do that, but unfortunately, there are way too many false positives that outweigh this minor advantage.  I may implement soundex code in the future gives the user additional fuzzy logic matches.

Answer (score 0):

Can get the brief idea about the question, but one point need to be clarify:
why the result do not have 
1   Another song    3   3:23
record? since it can be treated as duplicate with those 
3   song    4   4:01
4   song    4   6:33
records?

I just write a simple script in tsql to solve, the efficiency is low, just check as reference.

```
 drop table #t;
drop table #result;

create table #t 
(
id int ,
songName varchar(100),
artistID int,
duration varchar(20)
)
insert into #t
select '0',  'This is a song'   ,    '5'  ,       '3:43' union all
select '1',  'Another song'     ,    '3'  ,       '3:23' union all
select '2',  '01-This is a song',    '5'  ,       '3:42' union all
select '3',  'song'             ,    '4'  ,       '4:01' union all
select '4',  'song'             ,    '4'  ,       '6:33' union all
select '5',  'Another record'   ,    '2'  ,       '2:45'

select * from #t
select * into #result from #t where 1 = 0

declare @sName varchar(100)
declare @id int
declare @count int

declare c cursor for 
select id, songName from #t

open c
fetch next from c into @id, @sName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @count = COUNT(*) from #result where id = @id
    if @count = 0 
    begin
        select @count = COUNT(*) from #t where songName like '%'+@sName+'%'
        --select @count , @sName
        if @count > 1
        begin
            insert into #result select *  from #t where songName like '%'+@sName+'%' and id not in (select id from #result)
        end
    end
fetch next from c into @id, @sName
end
close c
deallocate c

select * from #result
```

Comment: They should only match if the artistID's are the same.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but what is "tsql"?  This makes no sense to me since I'm using VB.NET & SQLite.